# Draw filled Text on cv::Mat? (OpenCV C++)

Tags: c++, opencv, fonts, font-rendering

I'm attempting to draw some filled text onto an image stored in a [`cv::Mat`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html) object using OpenCV's C++ library.

---

Most of the [existing tutorials out there](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-put-a-text-in-an-image-in-opencv-using-cplusplus) make use of the [`putText`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d6/d6e/group__imgproc__draw.html#ga5126f47f883d730f633d74f07456c576) function.

The following minimal example:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core/mat.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>

int main()
{
    cv::Mat img = cv::Mat::zeros(300, 300, CV_8UC3);

    cv::putText(img, "TEST", cv::Point(50, 150), cv::FONT_HERSHEY_DUPLEX, 3, CV_RGB(255, 255, 255));

    cv::imshow("test", img);
    cv::waitKey(1);
    std::system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

Produces the following output:

[image]

However, I would like the text to be filled, instead of only having the borders visible.

---

According to the [`putText` documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d6/d6e/group__imgproc__draw.html#ga5126f47f883d730f633d74f07456c576), the `lineType` argument should be used to make the text filled.

Attempting to pass the [`cv::FILLED`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d6/d6e/group__imgproc__draw.html#gaf076ef45de481ac96e0ab3dc2c29a777) enum as the `lineType` argument to the `putText` call as such:

```
cv::putText(img, "TEST", cv::Point(50, 150), cv::FONT_HERSHEY_DUPLEX, 3, CV_RGB(255, 255, 255), 1, cv::FILLED);
```

results in no apparent changes to the output image:

[image]

I'm aware that I can simply make the `thickness` argument to the `putText` call higher to simulate a text fill, however I'm looking for a way to actually fill the text here, ideally without any text borders at all.

---

What is the proper way to draw filled text onto a `cv::Mat` image using OpenCV's C++ library?

Thanks for reading my post, any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: IIRC there's a freetype module in contrib, and when you have Qt as a HighGUI backend there's an extension to render text using that. Or use some text rendering library directly. The Hershey fonts are extremely limited.

Comment: try a different font. they differ in how they're drawn.

Comment: Did you try to provide negative value for `thickness` ?

Comment: @ElvisOric I did, attempting to use `-1` for the `thickness` argument results in a C++ memory error at the `putText` call. It appears there's an assertion statement that checks whether `thickness` is greater than 0.